# Count number of data in each cell of a datafarme

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with two columns Rt1 and Rt2.

```
df<-data.frame(Subject = c(rep(1,15), rep(2,15)), RT1=rep(seq(100,1500,100),2), RT2 = rep(seq(200,3000,200),2))
```

For various reasons, I want to count the number/frequency of datapoints that fall on each cell of a 4*4 grid, for each subject. Here, the datapoint are the same for the 2 subjects, but for the actual data, it is not the case.

For example, let's say the value of my grid are :

```
x_axis<-c(220,350,700,1250,1800)
y_axis<-(100,700,1400,2500,3500)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ6H8.png)

So basically I just want to get something that return me the number of point in each cell of the grid above, the desire output being something like :

```
df2<-data.frame("<x1"= c(1,0,0,0,0),
                "x1-x2"= c(0,2,0,0,0),
                "x2-x3"= c(0,0,4,0,0),
                "x4-x5"= c(0,0,0,3,0)
                )
```

Please note that this example is only for one subject (for clarity sake)

I do know how to do this, by simply counting the number of point in each "case", like :

```
df%>%
  group_by(Subject)%>%
  count(between(df$RT1,0,180),between(df$RT2 ,0,210))%>%
  set_names(c("RT1","RT2","n"))%>%
  filter(if_all(RT1:RT2, ~ . %in% TRUE))
```

However this is highly inefficient, as I should paste this code for each and every cell of all of my conditions.

I would really appreciate any help on this,

Thank you,

Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using joins to assign the cell number, then counting and adding 0's for any missing combinations. An upside to this approach is that you could easily make the categories vary by subject, if necessary, by adding the Subject to the join (assuming it's added to the lookup table).

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  left_join(data.frame(x_axis = c(0,x_axis)), join_by(closest(RT1 > x_axis))) |>
  left_join(data.frame(y_axis = c(0,y_axis)), join_by(closest(RT2 > y_axis))) |>
  count(Subject, x_axis, y_axis) |>
  tidyr::complete(x_axis, y_axis, fill = list(n=0))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 25 × 4
   x_axis y_axis Subject     n
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
 1      0    100       1     2
 2      0    100       2     2
 3      0    700      NA     0
 4      0   1400      NA     0
 5      0   2500      NA     0
 6    220    100       1     1
 7    220    100       2     1
 8    220    700      NA     0
 9    220   1400      NA     0
10    220   2500      NA     0
# ℹ 15 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table(
  cut(df$RT2, c(0, y_axis), right = FALSE),
  cut(df$RT1, c(0, x_axis), right = FALSE)
)

#                   [0,220) [220,350) [350,700) [700,1.25e+03) [1.25e+03,1.8e+03)
# [0,100)                 0         0         0              0                  0
# [100,700)               2         1         0              0                  0
# [700,1.4e+03)           0         0         3              0                  0
# [1.4e+03,2.5e+03)       0         0         0              6                  0
# [2.5e+03,3.5e+03)       0         0         0              0                  3
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'm not used to table, how can I group my data ? I did not mentionned it for claritry sakes, but my df have two additionnal columns, one for subjects (S<-c(301:316)) and one for each condition that I have in my experiment.

Comment: Hard to say, but if this solves the original request maybe the more complex one warrants a new post. Just be careful to be clear about the input and the expected input.